# Merging the results of multiple async loaders

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

The current app I have inherited is using Angular 1.x and angular-translate, which makes use of the static file loader:

```
    $translateProvider
        .useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: '/bundles/backend/js/global/translates/locale-cms-',
            suffix: '.json'
        })
```

I need to load an *additional* resource `/api/1/translations?lang=en` (for instance using `useUrlLoader`) and would like to know if this is possible, as I cannot get it working (I am reading [the docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading), mind you)... Would I need to create a custom loader that awaits the result of both HTTP requests and merges the results or can this be done using the existing machinery?

Preferably, I would just like to tack on the `.useUrlLoader` bits and have two requests fire off automatically and have their results get merged without me doing much else than calling `forceAsyncReload(true)`.

I did an initial POC using the synchronous `.translations()` API, which proved that using a sync loader followed by an async loader worked as intended; merging the results. This got my hopes up, but have not had much luck with the async bit.

Comment: If I understand you well, those are promises, right? You can use Promise.all https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Yeah, I know what promises are :-) (even though it's the pre-standard jQuery type of Promise.) But what you are implicitly suggesting is re-implementing the url loader and the static file loader and call them behind a custom implementation. I already considered this, but that is quite a bit of work, so that is why I was wondering if I could use the existing API without redoing the loader part when using two async loaders.